# Integrate Nav bar in to main project (ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am making an Application for my internship for event management of the firm. I am building the application on android studio.

I am building the app along with a sliding navigation bar, the navigation bar has been built as a separate android studio project.

Now, I wish to integrate the Navigation bar as a static element of all pages of the application, but don't know how to do so.

If anybody knows how can I integrate the Navigation bar in my main project, please do share your ideas.

Comment: What kind of navigation bar are you using? [Googles Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) or some github dependencies like [this](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer)?

Comment: `Googles Design Support Library`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey! I think I know how to get your projects merged, because I really had that kind of problem too with my own projects. It helped me to download and open an example project from github. Just follow my guide:

**Solution:**

- Download and open [MaterializeYourApp](https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp) in Android Studio
- Compare the used import methods with yours and use it side-by-side
- Important files: `includes_toolbar.xml`, `drawer_header.xml`

A really good tutorial is given here: [Design Support Library (I): Navigation View](http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/)
I can not really insert code snippets because you need the whole project..

Please rate my answer & give me feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Making A New App From From Beginning Then I Recomand To Do Using Material Drawer Templet.  Which Is Easy To Implement And Easy To Modify, 
Just Copy That Template to android studio library, and make new project from it.
 I Have Put Link To Download Template Library,

**It Will save A Lot Of Time To Program A Drawer.**

[Link To Download Template And Description](https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template)